# angular-meteor: Can I add (push) items to $scope var just after subscription resolves?

Tags: angular-meteor

I subscribe to a Meteor collection; then bind the collection to a $scope var and add some items to $scope. Then, the new items just disappear. Is that correct behavior?

1) subscribe to meteor collection

2) (when promise from subscription resolves ...) `$scope.collection = $meteor.collection(MeteorCollection, false); // note: no autoBind`

3) $scope.collection.push(item) // can be several items

4) they just 'disappear' from `$scope` // it seems `$scope` refreshes from Meteor Collection (that doesn't have those items)

Can somebody explain this behavior? Or, am I doing something (very) wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: is it possible that there are no permissions in the server to update? can you share an exmaple?